# Setting base_url in a multidomain setup?

Tags: configuration, uri

I have functionality that relies on having $base_url set in the settings.php file, but I have a multidomain site in order to keep languages separate.

The sections of my site are www.mysite.com and www.de.mysite.com. If I set base_url to "www.mysite.com" I get German language content on www.mysite.com.

How do I set the base_url for a multi-domain, multi-lingual setup so that things like my image style generation can work correctly?

This is a single install, not multisite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have 1 site in `sites/www.mysite.com` in your drupal setup and are trying to avoid having `sites/www.mysite.com` and `sites/www.de.mysite.com` ... ? So you're trying to edit 1 `settings.php` file.

You could create the above drupal sub-sites .... or try this less invasive approach.

Create a `sites.php` file if you're using Drupal 7 (you didnt specify your drupal version).

See this [documentation page on sites.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/sites!example.sites.php/7) It allows you to define configuration folders (where settings.php lives) per site in an array. This file is placed at `DRUPAL_ROOT/sites/sites.php`

```
// contents of sites.php
// URL = folder in sites directory.
$sites['www.mysite.com'] = 'mysite.com';
$sites['www.de.mysite.com'] = 'de.mysite.com';

// make a settings.php with unique $base_url in each directory above.
```

@kalabro's response is basically the same, except this is trumping the auto-discovery behavoir and making the settings directory explicitly set in PHP code.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you need separate settings.php file for each site.
You can create special folder for each domain in your `sites` directory and set custom `$base_url` in each settings.php file.

```
.
+-- all
¦   +-- modules
¦   +-- README.txt
¦   L-- themes
+-- default
¦   +-- default.settings.php
¦   +-- files
¦   L-- settings.php
L-- de.mysite.com
    L-- settings.php
L-- ru.mysite.com
    L-- settings.php
```

Documentation about site folders: http://drupalcode.org/project/drupal.git/blob/c5d6e6334fb7a71ecf1dbc7e06a7de8ad9547b27:/sites/default/default.settings.php#l25

Comment: This is not a multisite install. It's a multiple-subdomain single site.

Comment: @beth I guess It doesn't matter.

Comment: @beth did you find a fix for this? I have the same issue. I don't want to seperate the site into a multi-site architecture, but find a way to set 2 different base_url depending on the domain.